# Horizontal scrollView does not scroll

Tags: ios, image, swift, uiscrollview

I've followed a tutorial on the internet explaining how to make a scrollview with paging.

When I only want to show 1 image it works. But I need 3 labels and an Image. I've put everything on my storyboard. But when running on device/ simulator I can't scroll.

```
//Scrollview
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
var pageImages: [UIImage] = []
var pageViews: [UIImageView?] = []

@IBOutlet weak var blogImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var blogTussenTitel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var blogTitel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var blogbeschrijving: UILabel!


var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.sideMenuController()?.sideMenu?.delegate = self;
   if isMenuOpen() == true { disableObjects() } else { enableObjects() }

        // SrollView
    // 1
    pageImages = [UIImage(named: "photo1.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "photo2.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "photo3.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "photo4.png")!,
        UIImage(named: "photo5.png")!]

    let pageCount = pageImages.count

    // 2
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    pageControl.numberOfPages = pageCount

    // 3
    for _ in 0..<pageCount {
        pageViews.append(nil)
    }

    // 4
    let pagesScrollViewSize = scrollView.frame.size
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: pagesScrollViewSize.width * CGFloat(pageImages.count),
        height: pagesScrollViewSize.height)

    // 5
    loadVisiblePages()

}

func loadVisiblePages() {
    // First, determine which page is currently visible
    let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
    let page = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0)))
    // Update the page control
    pageControl.currentPage = page
    // Work out which pages you want to load
    let firstPage = page - 1
    let lastPage = page + 1
    // Purge anything before the first page
    for var index = 0; index < firstPage; ++index {
        purgePage(index)
    }
    // Load pages in our range
    for index in firstPage...lastPage {
        loadPage(index)
    }
    // Purge anything after the last page
    for var index = lastPage+1; index < pageImages.count; ++index {
        purgePage(index)
    }
}

func loadPage(page: Int) {
    if page < 0 || page >= pageImages.count {
        // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
        return
    }
    // 1
    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
        // Do nothing. The view is already loaded.
    } else {
        // 2
        var frame = scrollView.bounds
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
        frame.origin.y = 0.0
        // 3
        let newPageView = UIImageView(image: pageImages[page])
        newPageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        newPageView.frame = frame
        scrollView.addSubview(newPageView)
        //Image inladen
        //self.blogImage.image = pageImages[page]
        // 4
        pageViews[page] = newPageView
    }
}

func purgePage(page: Int) {
    if page < 0 || page >= pageImages.count {
        // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
        return
    }
    // Remove a page from the scroll view and reset the container array
    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
        pageView.removeFromSuperview()
        pageViews[page] = nil
    }
}


func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    loadVisiblePages()
}
```

Someone who can solve the problem?
Thanks in advance!
Kind regards, Hannes

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `UIScrollView height` not more than `View height` itself.

UIScrollView setting

[image]

View setting

[image]

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scroller: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 2300)
        scroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
        scroller.scrollEnabled = true

    }

}
```